# What poster is hanging in Raj's apartment on Big Bang Theory?

Tags: props, the-big-bang-theory

I was watching Big Bang Theory this evening and a poster on the wall caught my eye. It is momentarily featured on the episode that aired 1.14.16 as Sheldon apologizes to Raj's girlfriend for the first time. The poster is featured on several episodes (that feature Raj's apartment as a set) but not all of them. The most obvious feature is 2011 in the text at the bottom of the poster. When I froze the image and zoomed in, I thought I could read REIMAGE DOCUMENTARIES but I think I'm incorrect on that. The design features a beaker with a green liquid and a martini shape above it. There are strong angled stripes as well. Any information would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 11):

It appears to be this poster from [Science of Cocktails](http://www.sfgate.com/style/benefits/article/Exploratorium-investigates-Science-of-Cocktails-3161528.php) (or at least pretty similar to it).:

[image: Science of Cocktails]

I used Googles reverse image search to find this, using this image as the reference, in case you want to find more similar images (there's a few variations of this one):
[image: Reference Image]

Comment: https://www.casimireffect.us/project/exploratorium-science-of-cocktails